# Mysql: Is null does not work with other sentences

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

`is null` is not working if it's grouped with other sentences

this is the piece of sql that I want to run

```
SELECT * from `sms_inbox` where `from` is not null and `from` != '' and
received_date in (
select max(received_date) as received_date
from sms_inbox where user_id is NULL group by `from`
order by received_date desc
) order by `received_date` desc
```

If I only run this part of code it works

```
select max(received_date) as received_date, user_id
from sms_inbox where user_id is NULL group by `from`
order by received_date DESC
```

[image]

but if I use the full consult it does not work
[image]

Comment: What data are you expecting to get from the full query?  You are getting a list of `received_date`s in the inner query and then you are using those to filter the outer/main query.  What *exact* data are you looking for?  The main query doesn't filter on `user_id`, it's filtering on `from` and `received_date`.

Answer (score 1):

`select max(received_date) as received_date, user_id from sms_inbox where user_id is NULL group by 'from' order by received_date DESC` 
Returns a list of recieve_dates where user_id is null.

Then you do `SELECT * from 'sms_inbox' where received_date in(SUB_QUERY)`.  No where in this query do you filter out `user_id = null`.  All your doing is matching recieve_dates.  So I think you have records with the same `received_date` where the user_id is both null and not null.  Those not null are leaking in because you never removed them.